# Set background color of an li element, with list-style set to none

Tags: html, css

```
 <aside class="-menu">
    <ul class="-menu-ul">
      <li><div class="-menu-items">Phones</div><div class="-menu-count">15</div></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWBqzG)

I would like to set the background color of a li element on hover with the structure above.

I am using this style to tidy things up, remove list markers and set the background color on hover

```
.-menu{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
}
.-menu-items{
    float: left;
}
.-menu-count{
    float: right;
}
ul.-menu-ul{
    list-style:none;
}
ul.-menu-ul li{
    clear: both;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.-menu-ul li:hover{
background-color: #cdd4c4;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the `li` is 0 because it's children are floated, so you need to clear the float for the hover to appear.

```css
.scenes-menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
}

.scenes-menu-items {
  float: left;
}

.scenes-menu-count {
  float: right;
}

ul.scenes-menu-ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.scenes-menu-ul li {
  clear: both;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scenes-menu-ul li:hover {
  background-color: #cdd4c4;
}
```

```html
<aside class="scenes-menu">
  <ul class="scenes-menu-ul">
    <li>
      <div class="scenes-menu-items">Phones</div>
      <div class="scenes-menu-count">15</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you float the divs they're removed from the document flow and the `<li>` collapses and acts like it has no content, which is where you applied your hover rule. The easy way to restore the hover behavior is to add `overflow: auto` to your `<li>` rule.

**[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWPmZr)**